# Как зарегистрировать собственную консольную команду типа webpack или vue?

Tags: node.js, cmd, webpack, shell

Как создать собственную консольную команду типа `webpack` или `vue`, которую предлагают `webpack-cli` и `vue-cli`, соответственно?

В принципе, до этапа развёртывания npm-проекта всё понятно. Далее, насколько я догадываюсь, нужно в js-коде как-то прописать команду регистрации новой консольной команды. После этого нужно будет опубликовать библиотеку и после её глобальной установки новая консольная команда должна быть доступна.

Для меня непонятен момент регистрации консольной команды, чтобы она была доступна из консоли. Как это будет выглядеть в коде?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого используется ключевое слово `bin` в `package.json`.

```
{ "bin" : { "myapp" : "./cli.js" } }
```

https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#bin

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ!